# How to set text link as the actual URL and not the text tag from HTML

Tags: java, android, twitter

I've been trying to figure this one out for a bit using patterns or other utils but haven't gotten it to work just yet.

Say I have an HTML link:

```
 <a href="http://www.google.com">Google, Inc.</a>
```

I want to make a link into a text view BUT set the text of the link as the actual URL not Google, Inc.

So for example if the data I received is:

--Hey if you want to try a search go to `<a href="http://www.google.com">Google, Inc.</a>` and it's easy as that.

I want it to display as:

*--Hey if you want to try a search go to http://www.google.com and it's easy as that.*

Instead of:

*--Hey if you want to try a search go to Google, Inc. and it's easy as that.*

Html.fromHtml() makes it show as "Google, Inc." automatically, but isn't the result that I want.

Also, I don't need this to work for specifically this example, I need it to work for all html links as I don't know what links I will get as data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using [Linkify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aautoLink) and parsing the Strings yourself to create the links you want.

Set Linkify to look for raw web addresses and turn them into links in your text:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="web"
    />
```

This function will pull the raw address out the html tags:

```
public String parseLinks(String raw) {
    String openTag = "<a href=\"";
    String closeTag = "</a>";
    String result = "";

    int start = 0;
    int middle = raw.indexOf(openTag);
    int end;
    while(middle > -1) {
        result += raw.substring(start, middle);

        end = raw.indexOf("\">", middle);
        result += raw.substring(middle + openTag.length(), end);

        start = raw.indexOf(closeTag, end) + closeTag.length(); 
        middle = raw.indexOf(openTag, start);
    }

    result += raw.substring(start, raw.length());
    return result;
}
```

Understand that this function does no error checking, I recommend adding this yourself.

Now simply pass the String returned from parseLinks() to your TextView, like this:

```
textView.setText(parseLinks(rawHTML));
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I can't upvote your answer Sam but this worked for me. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

it's actually pretty tricky .... but i have found a way to do so.

Thanks to SO for that.

here is the answer:

```
TextView tvYourTextView = ( TextView ) findById( R.id.yourTextViewThatShowsALink );

tvYourTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()); //that will make your links work.
```

PS:
Don't forget to use `Html.fromHtml("your content as html")`